# Is there any way to check the source if it is a username field by android accessibility service?

Tags: android, accessibilityservice

I'm looking for a way to check the source of an event which is implemented by accessibility service to see if it is a username field or not.
I found there is a way to check the field if it is a password like below:

```
 if (event.isPassword()){
            Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
            arguments.putCharSequence(AccessibilityNodeInfo
                    .ACTION_ARGUMENT_SET_TEXT_CHARSEQUENCE, "android");
            source.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_SET_TEXT, arguments);}
```

well I want to detect the username field either, since if I used (!event.isPassword()) it detects for example url text box and even search-boxes, here is my conditions:

```
 if (source != null && event.getClassName().equals("android.widget.EditText") && getEventType(event).equals("TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED"))
```

Comment: Are you trying to detect from an application you wrote?  Or any potential third party application?

Comment: for third party applications, like chrome, firefox

Answer (score 3):

There is no concept in Android of a "username" field, as distinct from other types of fields. You have no reliable means of determining whether a given `EditText` is for a "username", a person's last name, or for the first few words of a poem.

Note that your `isPassword()` approach is also somewhat unreliable. It is possible to create an `EditText` widget that shrouds password entries without using built-in password capabilities, and for those cases I would expect `isPassword()` to return `false`. Conversely, a developer can use a `password` type `EditText` for entering information other than a password. There is also the case where the `EditText` allows the user to hide and show the password; with the password showing, I do not know what `isPassword()` will return.